# Android : Having issue with using one class' instance to another class

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm creating sign_up and sign_in page and data that type into editview will be store in database.
So for database I create one class named DBAdapter.java and my anotherfile is signup.java and login.java.
So I want to do that when I click on submit button data will be store in database.
But issue is that I cannot use DBAdapter.java's instance db into onclick event of submit button and same issue with login button in login.java file.

**thanks** in advance...

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
    public static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "LastName";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "UserName";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";    
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "master";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "register";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "FirstName text not null, LastName text not null, " 
        + "UserName text not null, Password text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

and signup.java

```
public class SignUp extends Activity {

    private EditText firstname;
    private EditText lastname;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;

    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String user_name;
    public String pass_word;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_fname);
        lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_lname);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_uname);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ev_password);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View v) {              
                first_name = firstname.getText().toString();
                last_name = lastname.getText().toString();
                user_name = username.getText().toString();
                pass_word = password.getText().toString();



                Intent goToNextActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), link.class);
                startActivity(goToNextActivity);


            }
        });
```

Comment: are these methods marked public? It would be better if we could see some code.

Comment: @Samuh i edit my que...my issue is i cant use DBAdapter's instance in onclick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more of a hack, I think, but what stops you from having this?

```
private DBAdapter db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = new DBAdapter(this);
```

I'd like to find a more elegant solution myself, as there are multiple needs for this in my apps too.

Comment: Thank you so much..for now it's work... but if i gettin any issue i'll write that issue here and notify u but it is done for now...so thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Harry... Have you tried:

```
final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
```

instead of:

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
```

JAL